# EditorGrid panel + button - reloading data problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

I am developing an application in ExtJs using Rails, wherein there's a tab panel. The main tab contains the list of buttons on the left . Clicking on each button would open a new tab, and would render a grid or form. When i add new record from the form, it is displayed at once on the grid, but if i close the tab panel and click on the button again, no grid is displayed.

How to load the grid along with the data again ?

P.S: when i manually refresh the browser, it's displayed again !!

Thanks in advance !!

MyCode :

```
//** MyUnit.js in Units controller**//

MyUnit = Ext.extend(MyUnitUi, {
         initComponent: function() {
        MyUnit.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

             //Insert records...

                var sbtn=Ext.getCmp('btnSave');

                sbtn.on('click',function(){
                var grid = Ext.getCmp('maingrid');
                var unitname =  Ext.getCmp('unitname').getValue();
                var description =  Ext.getCmp('description').getValue();

                var frm=Ext.getCmp('myform');

                Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/units',
                method: 'POST',

                params: {'data[unitname]':unitname,'data[description]':description}

        });
                var grid=Ext.getCmp('maingrid');
                grid.store.reload();
                grid.show();
                frm.hide();
             });

});

//** MyViewport.js in Test1 Controller **//

    var unit_bt =Ext.getCmp('btnUnit');
       unit_bt.on('click', function(){
       var unit_el =Ext.getCmp('tabcon');
       var tab = unit_el.getItem('tab_unit');
       if(tab)
       {
           tab.show();
       }else{
            unit_el.add({
                title    : 'Unit of Measurement',
                html     : 'I am new unit',
                activeTab: 0,
                closable : true ,
                id: 'tab_unit',
                autoLoad:{url:'/units',scripts:true}
                //store.load({params:{start:0, limit:25}})

            }).show();
            }
       });

//** Units/index.html **//
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Auto Generated with Ext Designer -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>unit.xds</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyUnit.ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyUnit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyUnitStore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xds_index.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @rashmi.. can you post your code?

Comment: @Abdel : have posted the code.

Comment: can you also post the code where you initialize your grid? My guess is you have your grid rendered into the tab. Then when you close your tab, your grid is removed along with your tab, so that's why it's disappear on the second try. Try post more, so we can help.

Comment: @Lionel :yes your guess is absolutely correct! Well i've posted the index.html page. The code in Viewport.js i.e url: /units would render the units/index.html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All : Thanks for your effort. Well my friend found the solution.

The problem got solved just by adding the following line of code in units.js again :

```
var grid=Ext.getCmp('maingrid');
grid.store.reload();
```